# How to deploy a next.js + mongo app to AWS (or any other service like G Cloud)?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, next.js

I just have some experience developing in JS but almost nothing in devops, and there's a lot of documentation but I don't really know where to start.

I built a next.js app (both frontend and backend) connected to mongo db. They run fine locally using docker-compose. Now I would like to deploy them to aws, also because I need to store on S3 files needed by the application.

What services do I tipically need? should I deploy my app to EC2, or use AWS amplify, or any other service like google cloud for example?

Can I deploy my images just how they are, including mongo, to EC2? Or should I, for example, just deploy next.js and connect it to a managed mongo db, which I suppose is an additional cost.

I know it is a pretty generic question, if you can just point me to the tools I need to manage the whole deploy process then I'll find out how to use them. Currently all the code (including Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml) is on github.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the perfect answer since the question is very general and AWS provides a lot of features but I'll give it a go.

1. For JS app you could use a AWS Elastic Beanstalk which is for setting up web applications easily as it creates all the resources like EC2, load balancers, etc. Since you're new to AWS you can check this service out instead of manually creating EC2. Even if you use AWS Elastic Beanstalk you will still have access to the EC2 and other resources created by AWS Elastic Beanstalk. You'll get exposure to various different services which can help speed up your application.
2. For images S3 would be a great choice. However, depending on how frequently data is accessed I would look up the different S3 options as well as backup options.
3. As for your DB, MongoDB would work but you'd need to run it on a EC2 and maintain it yourself. AWS has different managed database option such as DynamoDB in your case but it all depends on the tools you require, budget, etc.